# Altering Webform email %value before sending email

Tags: 7, webforms, emails, forms

I summon your wisdom on this day because I can't figure out how to **alter submitted Webform values** that are used in **email templates**.

Here's my situation:

I have a **"contact us" form** (set with Webform API) with first name, last name, email and message fields. Nothing spectacular. The submitted values are sent by email to the administrator.

In this *webform setting > Email subject*, I have this template:

```
[NAMEOFMYSITE | question from %value[first_name] %value[last_name]
```

Everything works fine. But my problem appears when the user forgets to put an **uppercase** in last name or first name value. It doesn't look professional in the email subject. And I want to **force** these two values with an uppercase as first letter to get something like:

```
NAMEOFMYSITE | question from John Doe
```

And never:

```
NAMEOFMYSITE | question from john doe
```

I tried to **alter submitted values** because I thought template's `%value` were based on it:

```
function pwe_webform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  [...]
  $form['#submit'][] = 'contactus_webform_submit'; // callback function on submit
}

function contactus_webform_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['values']['submitted']['last_name'] = ucfirst($form_state['values']['submitted']['last_name']);
  $form_state['values']['submitted']['first_name'] = ucfirst($form_state['values']['submitted']['first_name']);
}
```

But even if I succeed to modify them, the `%value` in email doesn't change.

Of course, I dpm `$form_state` tree to see where the submitted values appear in it and where the template's `%value` could find its origin. It appears on several levels:

- $form_state['input']['submitted']['last_name']
- $form_state['values']['submitted'][2]
- $form_state['values']['submitted_tree']['last_name']
- $form_state['complete form']['submitted']['last_name']['#value']
- $form_state['webform']['component_tree']['children'][2]['value'] *(but always empty)*

I altered **every variable** but the email value **still the same**. I'm about to ask myself if it is actually based on one of those variables... If not, on what is it based? And how can I alter it?

Please excuse the looooong post but I wanted it to be very clear. I hope you will help anyway :-(

Comment: I'm not sure if forcing uppercase is a good idea. Think of  Jeanne d'Arc - spelling as *Jeanne D'Arc* would be an error. Don't know how probable it is in your demography, but usually I would say it is more professional to leave a mistake your user did, than to introduce a spelling error to his content.

Comment: I totally agree with you @Mołot but I'm just the developer in that story, and I have to do some magic to execute requests from the company that I work for... :-(

Comment: I also found a very interesting comment in PHP manual about managing special string like Jeanne D'Arc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php#81258

Comment: I just found [this article](http://www.media-division.com/correct-name-capitalization-in-php/) - covers special cases better than comment you linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `hook_form_alter()`, add a new submission handler before the other submission handlers.

```php
function pwe_webform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'YOUR_WEBFORM':
      array_unshift($form['#submit'],'pwe_webform_form_submit');
      break;
  } 
}

function pwe_webform_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['input']['submitted']['last_name'] = ucfirst($form_state['input']['submitted']['last_name']);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! The origin of the template value is $form_state['values']['submitted']['last_name'] in validation hook!